# Add cell to collection view. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I created a collection of views and a custom cell via `xib`.

There is only a `Label` on the cell.

I have to enter the text through the `TextField`, fill in the array with this text, and put it in the cell.

I need to create a cell after each text entry in the `TextField`.

I haven’t worked with collections yet and don’t quite understand how it works.

That's all I have for now

**`CollectionCell.swift`:**

```
import UIKit
class CollectionPlayersCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerCell: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
     //someCode
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionPlayersView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextFIeld: UITextField!
    let playerCellId = "playersCell"
    var playersNames = [String]()

    @IBAction func inputNameField(_ sender: UITextField) {

        playersNames.append(nameTextFIeld.text!)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nibPlayersCell = UINib(nibName: playerCellId, bundle: nil)
        colecctionPlayersView.register(nibPlayersCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: playerCellId)
        notificationKeyboard()

    }


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: playerCellId, for: indexPath) as! CollectionPlayersCell
        cell.playerCell.text = playersNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return playersNames.count
    }


}
```

---

**Error:**

> 2019-12-06 19:34:45.823972+0200 Games[3143:174982] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>
> < /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0DF2A96E-E367-41D3-BE33-4F3FADE3EFCE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2818E8FD-23FE-4E86-925B-EC3F58EF6BFC/Games.app > (loaded)' with name 'playersCell''
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen , I attached a bug report below

Comment: The error suggests that you are trying to load a .xib named "playersCell", but that's not the name of the actual file.  You need to use the name of the actual file, like if the file is called "PlayersCollectionViewCell.xib" you need to change it to "PlayersCollectionViewCell"

Comment: @creeperspeak 
on the file Cell.xib
worth class PlayersCell.swift

Comment: @Gleb if the file is called Cell.xib then you need to do UINib(nibName: "Cell"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention your xib file name instead of "playerCellId"

```
let nibPlayersCell = UINib(nibName: playerCellId, bundle: nil)
```

It requires nibName = "YourNibName"

If your nib name is CollectionPlayersCell, then this should be like this -

```
let nibPlayersCell = UINib(nibName: "CollectionPlayersCell", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right!
Thank you so much.
The mistake was exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

To ask the collection view to update itself you need to call its `reloadData()` method.

So your `IBAction` should look like this:

```
@IBAction func inputNameField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        playersNames.append(nameTextFIeld.text!)
        collectionPlayersView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I get an error (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) after entering text

Comment: What line do you get that error? And note the capital I in `nameTextFIeld`, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes typo, I fixed it, but there is a mistake.
Points to a method in AppDelegate.swift

Comment: When I commented out the 'reloadData ()' method, it works. Otherwise, no

Comment: "a method in AppDelegate.swift" - which one?

Comment: @koen
Points to the class line itself  
     //class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: @Gleb In the logs what error it is printing?
One more thing, with which action you have connected this IBAction() ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cell identifier "playersCell" in your xib file 
and set the  `collectionView.delegate = self`  and `collectionView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: It is installed on both XIB and cell in collectionView